# Disable Sounds in 10.5 and 10.6

Tags: macos, command-line, audio, plist

I need to disable "Play user interface sound effects" and "Play feedback when volume is changed" in the Sound pref.pane **via terminal/unix command/ARD on multiple computers.**

fseventer shows /users/*$user*/preferences/com.apple.systemsound.plist being edited when I make changes to these properties in the GUI, but I don't see references for these settings in this .plist

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**defaults** is the command used to read/write preferences from the command line.

```
defaults write -g "com.apple.sound.beep.feedback" -int 0
defaults write "com.apple.systemsound" "com.apple.sound.uiaudio.enabled" -int 0
killall -HUP SystemUIServer
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work for the volume pops but it either isn't working for the general UI sounds or "Play user interface sound effects" doesn't do what I thought it does, which seems to be the cause because even when I disabled it via GUI it still exhibits the same behaviors I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Ian The general UI sounds (like dragging something to the trash or unmounting a volume) are in the `SystemSounds` folder, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To disable all sounds, you could try:

`sudo launchctl unload com.apple.audio.coreaudiod`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this as I'm not on the Mac right now, but an alternative would be to move the System sounds where OS X won't find them.

```
/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/Resources/SystemSounds
```

Comment: That probably would work, but it seems like a hack, and would cause trouble if you or somebody else wanted to reverse it, and didn't know where you'd put it.

Answer (score 0):

To silence UI sounds, enter this in Terminal:

> `defaults write com.apple.systemsound com.apple.sound.beep.volume -float 0`

This will set the volume slider for UI sounds to it's lowest value. Test it by pressing an `F` key not assigned to Exposé/Spaces/Dashboard/...

Comment: Fun fact: Set it to `0.5` and look at the slider position. It's just slightly above 25% -- it's not presented linearly to the user, probably to better approximate loudness perception.

Comment: Oh, nice detail :) (I wonder what else they have in stock..)